# How to filter (where clause) an array with undescoreJS under React Native?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I've got this array:

```
const stations = [{"number":31705,"name":"31705 - CHAMPEAUX (BAGNOLET)","address":"RUE DES CHAMPEAUX (PRES DE LA GARE ROUTIERE) - 93170 BAGNOLET","position":{"lat":48.8645278209514,"lng":2.416170724425901},"banking":true,"bonus":true,"status":"OPEN","contract_name":"Paris","bike_stands":50,"available_bike_stands":50,"available_bikes":0,"last_update":1465070874000},{"number":10042,"name":"10042 - POISSONNIÃˆRE - ENGHIEN","address":"52 RUE D'ENGHIEN / ANGLE RUE DU FAUBOURG POISSONIERE - 75010 PARIS","position":{"lat":48.87242006305313,"lng":2.348395236282807},"banking":true,"bonus":false,"status":"OPEN","contract_name":"Paris","bike_stands":33,"available_bike_stands":19,"available_bikes":14,"last_update":1465071301000},{"number":8020,"name":"08020 - METRO ROME","address":"74 BOULEVARD DES BATIGNOLLES - 75008 PARIS","position":{"lat":48.882148945631904,"lng":2.319860054774211},"banking":true,"bonus":true,"status":"OPEN","contract_name":"Paris","bike_stands":44,"available_bike_stands":39,"available_bikes":2,"last_update":1465071166000}];
```

I'm trying to filter it using the *where* clause like this:

```
console.log(_.filter(stations, function(v) { return v.number > 0 }));
```

But it returns an empty array. Do you know why?

Comment: working fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/bsqjo1sp/

Comment: Ok here is the real array if you wanna try: https://api.jcdecaux.com/vls/v1/stations?contract=Paris&apiKey=3a9169028401f05f02bcffd87f4a3963dcd52f63

Comment: still works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/pqLqw14j/1/

Comment: I can confirm it works fine: http://plnkr.co/edit/JZVQhIsXA2Tu6lB34Yaj?p=preview

Comment: @XavierC. you mention _where_ clause, but the code actually uses _filter_. Are you/us missing something?

Comment: Thanks guys. In fact, I didn't post the entire code but I couldn't get a working array because my fetch callback returned me a response.text() instead a response.json(). So I tried to iterate through a string... Anyway, I changed the code and it works! Thanks again for your help!